Using ifstream/ofstream with Visual Studio. ofstream only outputs last entered password instead of password for specific account
I am learning C++, and have been for about 3 weeks now. Right now, I am writing a program based off of a tutorial (don't worry, I know about tutorial hell. I learned the data types and functions one by one before going to tutorials on things I want to learn, like case in point).
So, my question is this - The reason I clicked on this tutorial is because I wanted to learn how to write/read from text files outside of the IDE using ifstream/ofstream. However the tutorial is kind of crap and doesn't expand on the specifics.
The program works in the command prompt with 4 different options:

Login
Register
Forgot password
Exit

Everything works as intended, and is all really basic and I understand it, EXCEPT THE PART I WANTED TO LEARN IN THE FIRST PLACE.
When clicking "forgot password", it asks the user to enter their username to find their password. If they enter a username that has been registered, it is supposed to give them the password to that username, but instead it gives the most recent password registered.
Now, the interesting thing to me is, you would think since it's not recognizing the password to the username, that would mean the username and password aren't connected and it would allow the user to login with any of the usernames registered and any of the passwords, but that isn't the case.
Is this happening because I have to write code to specify the username and password are linked, like maybe put them in sets when users register, or is it as simple as ifstream can't read the whole document only the last line and I need to use a different function?
I will post my whole code now, then below I will post the specific function in question. Also, just note that I just gave the variable count random numbers since the code will change them anyways, and Visual Studio was giving me problems when just initializing without a value.
Code:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <set>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

//gonna have 3 functions. login, registration, and forgot function with main we will make the  menu.


void login();
void registration();
void forgot();


int main() {
    int choice;
    cout << "\t\t\t\t______________________________________________________\n\n";
    cout << "\t\t\t\t              Welcome to the login page                 \n\n\n";
    cout << "\t  ______________   MENU  ________________________________\n\n\n";
    cout << "\t|         Press 1 to login                               |" << endl << endl;
    cout << "\t|         Press 2 to register                            |" << endl << endl;
    cout << "\t|         Press 3 if you have forgotten your password.   |" << endl << endl;
    cout << "\t|         Press 4 to EXIT.                               |" << endl << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    cout << endl;

    switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        login();
        break;

    case 2:
        registration();
        break;

    case 3:
        forgot();
        break;

    case 4:
        cout << "You have chosen to exit. The program will now close." << endl;
        break;

    default:
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << "\aInvalid input! Please try again." << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
        system("cls");
        main();
    }
}


void login() {
    int count = 5;
    string userid, password, id, pass;

    system("cls");

    cout << "\t\tPlease enter the username and password to the account you would wish to access." << endl;
    cout << "\t\t\t USERNAME " << endl;
    cin >> userid;
    cout << "\t\t\t PASSWORD " << endl;
    cin >> password;

    ifstream input("records.txt");
    while (input >> id >> pass) {
        if (id == userid && pass == password) {
            count = 1;
            system("cls");
        }


    }
    input.close();

    if (count == 1) {
        cout << userid << " Your login is successful!" << endl;
        main();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Username or password was incorrect. Please try again or register if you do not have an account." << endl;
        main();
    }
}

void registration() {
    int count = NULL;
    int confirm;
    string ruserid, rpassword, rid, rpass;
    system("cls");

    cout << "You have chosen to register an account. Please type in what you would like for your username." << endl;
    cin >> ruserid;
    cout << "You have chosen " << ruserid << " as your username. Now please type in what you would like for your password." << endl;
    cin >> rpassword;
    cout << "You have chosen " << ruserid << " as your username and " << rpassword << " as your password.\nConfirm? yes for yes, no for no." << endl;
    cin >> confirm;
    switch (confirm) {
    case 1: { cout << "You have confirmed this as your account info.\n\n"; break; }
    case 2: { cout << "You have cancelled making the account. Returning to registration page.\n"; cin.clear(); cin.ignore(); registration(); break; }
    default: { cout << "Invalid input. Returning to registration page.\n"; cin.clear(); cin.ignore(); registration(); break; }
    }

    /*ifstream input("records.txt");
      while(input >> id >> password)
      if (ruserid == id) {
      cout << "You have picked a username already taken. Please reregister with a different username. Tip: Choose one that is unique." << endl;
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore();
      system("cls");
      registration();
      }*/

    ofstream f1("records.txt", ios::app);
    f1 << ruserid << "    " << rpassword << endl;
    system("cls");
    cout << "Registration successful!\n";
    main();
}

void forgot() {
    int option;

    system("cls");
    cout << "You have forgotten the password? Press 1 to search your password by username or 2      to go back to the main menu\n\n";
    cin >> option;
    switch (option) {
    case 1:
        {
            int count = 0;
            string suserid, sid, spass, spassword;
            cout << "Please enter your username to regain password.\n\n";
            cin >> suserid;
            ifstream f2("records.txt");
            string line;
            while (f2>>sid>>spass) {
                if (sid == suserid) {
                    count = 1;
                }
            }
            f2.close();
            if (count == 1) {
                cout << "Your account has been found.\n";
                cout << "Your password is: " << spass << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "User not found. Returning to main menu." << endl;
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore();
                Sleep(1200);
                system("cls");
                main();
            }
            break;
        }

    case 2:
        {
            main();
        }
    default:
        {
            cout << "Invalid input. Returning to forgot password menu" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();
            system("cls");
            forgot();
        }
    }
}

The forgot() function is the one in question, with this specific part that's giving issues:
int count = 0;
string suserid, sid, spass, spassword;
cout << "Please enter your username to regain password.\n\n";
cin >> suserid;
ifstream f2("records.txt");
string line;
while (f2>>sid>>spass) {
    if (sid == suserid) {
        count = 1;
    }
}
f2.close();
if (count == 1) {
    cout << "Your account has been found.\n";
    cout << "Your password is: " << spass << endl;
}

I have tried making the userid/id/pass/password as global variables and using them instead of using different ones for each function (though, maybe by using the same variable, it would then know the password that went with the username created).
I have tried adding the variables in all functions as global, but not changing any of the variables in the functions, and just adding an if statement that says if(sid==suserid){spass==password}, but this just makes it not output any password.
I have also tried changing the if statement in the while loop to if(sid == suserid && spass == password).

When you find the corresponding entry, you need to break out of the loop. One way, but maybe not the best, is to do while ((f2>>sid>>spass) && count != 1) {

@ChrisMM Bro ty so much!  this doesn't work quite right sometimes it gives the correct password, the other half it gives the password registered after the correct one, I assume because it doesn't close fast enough, but you help me understand what the problem was so now I can find a way to fix it by playing around so ty so much

@ChrisMM Sorry for tagging you again, but I am brand new to the site. If there is a way to give you best answer or rep points or something please let me know as I can't seem to see any options

Side note, you are not allowed to call main from user code in C++; doing so results in undefined behavior.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

@MilesBudnek Ty for the tip, I am honestly very surprised this is the first time I have heard of that.

@PeteBecker Yeah, I am aware, just bad habbits tbh. But ty for the advice

<deleted the part about count, I noticed it's locally declared>. Also make sure your user names and passwords don't contain spaces, because that's your default separators.

@Gene ty for the advice but the problem has been solved by ChrissMM. Issue was ifstream basically just runs from the beginning to the end of the file so by including code to stop the ifstream when the username was found fixed it since the password is with the username. I am not sure how to close the question, but ty to all who gave advice and help!

You don't need to close the question. You can just answer it yourself. That said, you'd better fix the question to be more readable first.

Side note: you are using cin.clear(); cin.ignore(); incorrectly. Dont call those unless an actual IO error occurs (which you never check for). Also, calling ignore() without a parameter value will skip just 1 character, not the rest of the current line.

I put the two conditions in the wrong order. I've added an answer with them in the correct order which should fix the issue with it giving the next value.

@RemyLebeau The reasons I use cin.clear() and ignore() in this code is only when I am essentially restarting the program so I just do it as a safety measure to ensure no recent cin will be carried over. I don't necessarily use it because bad cin was entered, but just my way of clearing the most recent cin to ensure the program restart will start off with no cin remembered. Does system("cls") do this automatically? And if not then do you have a recommendation for a more correct way to do this?

When you find the corresponding entry, you need to break out of the loop. One way, but maybe not the best, is to do
while (count != 1 && (f2>>sid>>spass)) {

This will stop reading the files once the count has reached one. Note that the count != 1 is before the rest of it, so that it doesn't read the next line.
